# Rules of inference for set theory

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms

First of all, I'll give some context, just to clarify my mind, and hopefully some others as well. If you are familiar with this stuff you can **skip to the quoted main question**.

In order to start doing math, we need a common *formal language*, lets say we have the *set theory language*, which (for example) consists on the following *special symbols*

- $(,),\neg,\to,\vee,\wedge,\leftrightarrow,\forall,\exists,=,\in$

and an unlimited list of *variables*. Once we have defined the alphabet of our formal language, we need to define the syntax rules to build up valid *formulas*. For example

1. If $x$ and $y$ are *variables*, then $(x=y)$ and $(x\in y)$ are *formulas*.
2. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are *formulas*, then $\neg\alpha$, $(\alpha\to\beta)$, $(\alpha\vee\beta)$, $(\alpha\wedge\beta)$ and $(\alpha\leftrightarrow\beta)$ are *formulas*.
3. If $\alpha$ is a *formula* and $x$ is a *variable*, then $\forall x\alpha$ and $\exists x\alpha$ are *formulas*.

So, once we all speak in the same language, is not (still) our business to ask questions about our language itself.

Finally, if we want to prove stuff, we need two things

1. A list of *sentences* we assume to be *true*. This will be, for example, the ZFC axioms.
2. A list of *inference rules*, being each *inference rule* a list of descriptions of *sentences* (acording to the previously defined rules) which we call *premises* and a description of a *sentence*, which we call *conclusion*.

So, the *general rule* is that, if we have a list of sentences which fits all of some inference rule *premises* descriptions, and we know they are all *true*, then, the *sentence* built up from the *conclusion* description and our original sentences is also *true*.

Finally, the main question is,

> What are the "standard" *inference rules* for set theory?

Comment: See [First order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Deductive_systems) : usual Hilbert-style axioms with Modus Ponens. Alternatively, [Natural Deduction](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4).

Comment: See e.g. [The axioms of set theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/index.html#AxiSetThe) : "$\mathsf {ZFC}$ is an axiom system formulated in first-order logic with equality and with only one binary relation symbol $\in$ for membership."

Comment: See [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1780199/which-rules-of-inference-does-suppes-use).

Comment: Perhaps one way to summarize the links in the previous comments is that the standard inference rules are formulated for first order logic, without regard to set theory (or group theory, or any other kind of theory). Then, whatever theory one wishes to investigate, one adds new symbols and axioms that are special to the theory, but the rules of inference do not change.

Comment: Are you quoting from some textbook ? If so, perhaps going on you will find the def of first-order tehory with example : arithmetic, set theory.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No, I'm not quoting from any textbook, this are just my (probably wrong) thoughts in the topic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm not even a newcommer into logic, and I only wanted a complete list of inference rules for set theory, but, if I have understood your previous comments, the set theory language defined above is just a particular case of first order language, and these languages appear to have several equivalent inference rules defined on them.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So, is [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mathematical-logic-rules-inference/) list complete?

Comment: Maybe… See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system#Formal_deductions) for a sound and complete one.

Comment: See [this excellent book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Basic_Set_Theory.html?id=TCIX3qis9pUC) for issues like this.

Comment: What does $x|\alpha$ stand for?

Comment: @celtschk Informally, it stands for the set $x$ that verifies $\alpha$ for example, $\emptyset$ will be $x|\forall y y\not\in x$. We must only use it if the set $x$ is guaranteed to exist and to be unique.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Tenorio: Normally, if you just want to know the axioms of ZFC you can just go to Wikipedia and find them all. But given that you included the definite expression syntax "$x|a$", I presume that you actually want to have a **practical** formal system whose underlying theory is ZFC, rather than a pure FOL system. In that case, take a look at [this Fitch-style system based on many-sorted FOL](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684204/21820), which includes an axiomatization that is as strong as ZFC but is much more intuitive.

Comment: I think you would know how to add the definite expression syntax if you wish to. But note that it may be better to add [full abbreviation power (also called definitorial expansion)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1864310/21820), as it is more powerful. In particular, if "$x|a$" is well-defined in terms of some parameters then you have a definable function and can use rule (2) in my post. Secondly observe that even in absence of any choice principle rule (3) is conservative and stronger than your definite expression syntax (since it does not require uniqueness).

Comment: In fact, full abbreviation power rule (3) is already totally subsumed by the Fitch-style rule ∃elim (see my first linked post), and it is entirely natural for Fitch-style. In addition, it is much more natural to have a generalized definite expression syntax, allowing statements like "∀k∈N ( k>1 ⇒ ( p≠1 ∧ ∀x,y∈N ( x·y=p ⇒ x=1 ∨ y=1 ) where p>1 ∧ ∃d∈N ( p·d=k ∧ ∀q,e∈N ( q·e=k ⇒ p≤q ) ) ) )". This can be made even more elegant using rules (1) and (2), by first defining Prime(p) :≡ p≠1 ∧ ∀x,y∈N ( x·y=p ⇒ x=1 ∨ y=1 ), and LeastFactor := ( N k ↦ p | p>1 ∧ ∃d∈N ( p·d=k ∧ ∀q,e∈N ( q·e=k ⇒ p≤q ) ) ),

Comment: yielding "∀k∈N ( k>1 ⇒ Prime(LeastFactor(k)) )". So much cleaner! If you are interested in discussing further on foundations of mathematics, you're welcome to [the logic chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic).